# How to share a dynamic constant across modules?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I'm trying to properly modularise my code and keep things self contained, and build it all nicely chunked with webpack. The idea I'm wrestling with is how to get a constant shared across modules (i.e., something that would be in the global scope if put directly in the HTML).

Specifically, I have a logging module that looks like this:

```
'use strict';

import { v4 } from "uuid";

const ssid = v4();

function sendToLog(metric) {
    metric.ssid = ssid;
    // send to the api
}

// Send userAgent immediately
sendToLog({ ua: window.navigator.userAgent });
```

If I transpile that and just put it in the html file, then I later include, say, a WebVitals module

`<script defer src="./dist/webvitals.js"></script>`

```
import {getLCP} from 'web-vitals';

getLCP(sendToLog);
```

Then `ssid` will be the same in all of the calls to `sendToLog`. But, what I want to do is not inline the logging module, but instead have the WebVitals module (and others) import it:

`logger.js`:

```
'use strict';

import { v4 } from "uuid";

const ssid = v4();

export default function sendToLog(metric) {
    metric.ssid = ssid; 
}
```

and `webvitals.js`:

```
import {getLCP} from 'web-vitals';
import sendToLog from './logger';

getLCP(sendToLog);
```

how do I construct this so the `ssid` remains the same across every module that imports `logger.js`?

Comment: I would expect `logger.js` to only be parsed and executed once, regardless of how many modules import it. If you put a `console.log` in the body of `logger.js` and then import it from two other modules, how many logs do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I construct this so the `ssid` remains the same across every module that imports logger.js?

You already did. A module is evaluated only once, regardless how often it is imported. The top-level `const ssid` is essentially a static variable, an there is only a single `sendToLog` function, shared between all modules that import your logger.

Comment: Specifically, ES6 modules are proper singletons. Not only is the module parsed only once for multiple imports but all imports are guaranteed to get the same object, not merely similar looking copies of an object.